# Сделать ссылку на SVG

Tags: html, svg

Как сделать ссылку на SVG. Не открывается ссылка.

Comment: <div class = "map">
<svg viewBox = "0 0 514 497">

<a href="http://ссылка/">
<path d = "m 293.38734,0.92551184 c -0.77126,0 -1.54252,0 -2.31378,0 -0.15. z"/>

</a>

Answer (score 3):

Попытайся использовать атрибут **xlink:href** для того, чтобы задать адрес.

```
<a xlink:href="#"></a>
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 181.5 187.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 181.5 187.5;" xml:space="preserve">
            <a xlink:href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com">
              <g id="enter-button">
                <g id="text-enter">
                   <path id="e_1_" d="M92.3,19.5h-6.4c-0.2,0-0.4-0.2-0.4-0.4v-15c0-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.4h6.2c0,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.2c0,0.1,0,0.8,0,0.9
                 c0,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.2h-4.4c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4v5c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4h3.9c0,0,0.2,0,0.2,0.2c0,0.2,0,0.7,0,0.9
                 c0,0.2-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.2h-3.9c-0.2,0-0.4,0.2-0.4,0.4v5.3c0,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.4h4.5c0,0,0.1,0,0.1,0.1c0,0.1,0,0.9,0,1
                 C92.4,19.5,92.3,19.5,92.3,19.5z"/>
                 <path id="n" d="M99.9,19.6h-1.6v-8.7L94.7,11v8.6h-1.6V9.7h1.6V10c0.6-0.1,1.3-0.1,1.9-0.2c0.8-0.1,1.4-0.1,1.9-0.1
                 c0.9,0,1.3,0.4,1.3,1.1V19.6z"/>
                 <path id="t" d="M105.1,18.5v1.3H103c-0.6,0-1.1-0.5-1.1-1.1v-8h-1.3V9.3h1.3V6.1h1.4v3.1c0,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.2,0.2h1.7v1.3h-1.7
                 c-0.1,0-0.2,0.1-0.2,0.2v7.8H105.1z"/>
                 <path id="e" d="M113.7,18.7c0,0.8-0.4,1.2-1.2,1.2h-3.4c-0.8,0-1.2-0.4-1.2-1.2v-8c0-0.8,0.4-1.2,1.2-1.2h3.4
                 c0.8,0,1.2,0.4,1.2,1.2c0,0,0,3.3,0,3.8c0,0.5-0.5,0.5-0.5,0.5h-4v3.8h3.1v-1.9h1.4V18.7z M112.3,13.8v-3.1h-3.1v3.1H112.3z"/>
                 <path id="r" d="M121.3,10.8c-0.1,0-1.2,0-1.2,0s-0.1,0-0.1-0.1c0,0,0-0.1,0-0.1c0-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1-0.1l-1.4,0
                 c-0.6,0-1.1,0.5-1.1,1.1v8h-1.4V9.2h1.4v0.3c0.5-0.1,0.9-0.1,1.4-0.2c0.6-0.1,1-0.1,1.4-0.1c0.8,0,1.2,0.4,1.2,1.2v0.4
                 C121.4,10.7,121.4,10.8,121.3,10.8z"/>
                </g>
              </g>
            </a>
          </svg>
```